# update div value - JQuery Toastmessage-plugin

Tags: php, jquery

i have a php page that redirects (if successful) to another php page like this:

```
header('Location: completed.php?message=Successful operation. Data inserted for user: ' . $login->get_username() . ' . See home page for infos.');
```

Now in completed.php i have a div that echoes the received message:

```
<div id="msg">
<?php echo $_GET['message']; ?>
</div>
```

I'm using the 'Toastmessage-plugin' : [here..](http://akquinet.github.com/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/) , but i'm unable to display the $_GET in to the text of Toastmessage ..
I'm using this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.toastmessage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="styles/jquery.toastmessage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

...

<script type="text/javascript">
function showStickyNoticeToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showToast', {
            text: $('#msg').val(),
            sticky: true,
            position: 'bottom-left',
            type: 'notice',
            closeText: '',
            close: function () { console.log("toast is closed ..."); }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I've searched a lot , also for DOM Events and other events but i don't know what step take... maybe when the JQ function is loaded the div 'msg' has not yet received GET data ...? so how i update his value ?

The page i've read :
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950199/jquery-how-can-i-detect-if-the-html-has-changed-within-a-given-element) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628508/how-to-update-div-when-on-select-change-in-jquery).
I also tried with ajax but i'm less experienced in that language..

please help... :)  Thanks

EDIT @charlietfl

Ajax :  i've made a lot of tries... i can't find the code anymore!
Basically i call a php file with this code (take this as pseudocode):

```
<script type="text/javascript>
<!--
$('#choose').change(function(event) {
    $.get('messages.php', { selected: $('#msg').val() },
        function(data) {
            $('#update').html(data);   // other div wher store data
        }
    );            
}); 
</script>
```

....

```
<?php

$alfa = isset($_GET['message']) ? $_GET['message'] : 'nothing';
echo $alfa;
?>
```

Comment: show the ajax code and how you invoke the message with it

Comment: If you simply output the GET[message], the message MUST be there, unless you tamper with $_GET in your php code...

Comment: charlietfl ... look at my edit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: you use `$("#msg").val()` but `DIV` tags have not a "value".

Use `$("#msg").text()` (for plain-text)

or `$("#msg").html()`

to include also some HTML you may have in your code (pretty sure you need the first option).

Use `.val()` only with "valued" tags like `<input>` (works also with `<textarea>`).

See also: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Yes.. that was the right solution... using $("#msg").val() didn't work. I've changed it with $("#msg").text().. now got it working...Thanks to all.. bye!

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the message with `urlencode()` like:

```
$msg = "Successful operation etc. etc.";
header("Location: completed.php?message="+urlencode($msg));
```

Comment: @lollo ok, bear in mind that any complex string as GET parameter should be passed this way (expecially if it contains special characters like ampersand &)

Comment: @lollo Got the error maybe, check my other answer. To all, I don't know if its in-policy to give another answer (I felt it was right to do because it was totally unrelated).

Comment: @lollo You're welcome :) If you feel my answer is correct and the most satisfactory, plase upvote and accept the other answer, thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is likely that you are trying to call the message plugin before the ajax completes since the first 'A' in ajax stands for asynchronous.

In order to allow for the time required for the ajax to complete you would need to call your message plugin within the success callback of ajax.

Add `message` argument to function

```
function showStickyNoticeToast( message ) {
        $().toastmessage('showToast', {
            text: message,
            sticky: true,
            position: 'bottom-left',
            type: 'notice',
            closeText: '',
            close: function () { console.log("toast is closed ..."); }
        });
    }



$.post( url , dataToserver, function(data){         
      showStickyNoticeToast( $(data).text())
      $('#update').html(data); 

})
```

Comment: That's not the issue, the error is in "val()" and by the way ajax was mentioned only as an alternative, not as the actual implementation.

Comment: I realize val is incorrect, but where is the flaw in this scenario?

Comment: The original post didn't mention Ajax (only once, but as an alternative to another different implementation). 
And the main error was that the OP didn't retrieve correctly the value, not his use or misuse of Ajax (which wasn't shown at all). So I felt this answer, though syntactically and procedurally correct (I've read other posts by you and know you're very clever and expert) was inappropriate.
Now after a bunch of edits we have also an AJAX part in the OP...